# How to create a triangular shaped UI in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Please, I'd like to create a UI that looks like [image: this] in flutter, but I can't seem to create the areas that looks like triangles.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend you have a look at [Flutter Custom Clippers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers) plugin. You can find multiple shapes there.

Comment: Ok.. i think this is what I'm looking for.